# How to Stop a for loop, inside of a while Loop in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop, boolean

I am producing a simple athlete race time data entry form, I need it to ask every pass whether the user wants to continue if so then it goes again, if not then it exits the while loop. If the user has not entered atleast 4-8 pieces of data then it produces an error instead of printing out the times. I believe the error is due to after it goes through the while loop for the first time, it does not do another pass until it does 8 within the for loop. How would I get around this problem. Please explain your code, and relate it to the context I have given.

```
import time
datasets= []
carry_on = True


while carry_on == True:
    for i in range(0, 8):
        print("Inputting Data for Lane", i)
        gender = str(input("Is the athlete male or female ")) 
        athlete = str(input("What is the athletes name "))
        finishTime = float(input("What was the finishing time "))
        dataset = [gender, athlete, finishTime]
        datasets.append(dataset)
        decision = input("Would you like to add another lane ")
        if decision == "yes":
            carry_on = True
        else:
            carry_on = False

print("")

if 3 < i > 9:
    print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format("Gender","Athlete","Finish time"))
    ds = sorted(datasets, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=False)
    for s in ds:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format(s[0], s[1], s[2]))
else:
    print("You have not chosen enough lanes, please choose atleast 4")
```

Comment: `while carry_on:` is enough and `3 < i > 9` is just `3 < i`.

Comment: Have a look at [`break`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/simple_stmts.html#break) to go after `carry_on = False`

Comment: Thank you this solved it, If a formal answer is given I can make it correct for you.

Comment: Learn basics of programming first!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, LEARN THE BASICS

try break in for loop
not sure if while is required

```
for i in range(0, 8):
    print("Inputting Data for Lane", i)
    gender = str(input("Is the athlete male or female ")) 
    athlete = str(input("What is the athletes name "))
    finishTime = float(input("What was the finishing time "))
    dataset = [gender, athlete, finishTime]
    datasets.append(dataset)
    decision = input("Would you like to add another lane ")
    if decision != "yes":
        break
```

// going by your code and what you have asked

```
import time
datasets= []
carry_on = True


while carry_on == True:
    for i in range(0, 8):
        print("Inputting Data for Lane", i)
        gender = str(input("Is the athlete male or female ")) 
        athlete = str(input("What is the athletes name "))
        finishTime = float(input("What was the finishing time "))
        dataset = [gender, athlete, finishTime]
        datasets.append(dataset)
        decision = input("Would you like to add another lane ")
        if decision == "yes":
            carry_on = True
        else:
            carry_on = False
            break

print("")

if 3 < i > 9:
    print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format("Gender","Athlete","Finish time"))
    ds = sorted(datasets, key=lambda x:x[2], reverse=False)
    for s in ds:
        time.sleep(1)
        print("{0:<10}{1:<10}{2:<15}".format(s[0], s[1], s[2]))
else:
    print("You have not chosen enough lanes, please choose atleast 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

The for loop does 8 iterations no matter what, so you'll always enter 8 lanes. 
You can remove the for loop entirely, and replace it with a simple counter.
Increase the counter when the user chooses to add another lane, and when it reaches 8 - end the loop. 
Something like(in pseudo code) :

```
counter =0
while carry_on
  <read user input>
  if counter < 8
    <ask user to continue>
  if decision == "yes"
    counter++
    carry_on = true
  else
    carry_on = false
<handle input here>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use only one for loop, and break instruction:

```
for i in range(8):
    print("Inputting Data for Lane", i)
    gender = input("Is the athlete male or female ")
    athlete = input("What is the athletes name ")
    finishTime = float(input("What was the finishing time "))
    dataset = [gender, athlete, finishTime]
    datasets.append(dataset)
    decision = input("Would you like to add another lane ")
    if decision != "yes":
        break
```

Note that range(0, 8) can be written: range(8)

And input returns a string, so str(input(...)) is useless.

Moreover:

```
if 3 < i > 9
```

means:

```
if i > 3 and i > 9:
```

I think what you mean is:

```
if 3 < i < 9:
```

Finally: float(input(...)) could raise a ValueError exception if the user enters something that is not a number. You should add a try: except: construct.